# verificar variable php antes de hacer el submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

estoy aprendiendo sobre la marcha y medio bloqueado de a ratos con algun tema.
Tengo un form con 2 botones en mi pagina detalle.php :

```html
                    <form action="carrito.php" method="POST" name="compra">
                        <input name="id_txt" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id?>" />
                        <input name="nombre" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $nombre?>" />
                        <input name="precio" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $precio?>" />
                        <input name="cantidad" type="hidden" value="1" />
                        <input name="stock" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $stock?>" />
                        <?php 
                        if ($stock>0) { ?>
                        <div id="detalle_caja_botones">   
                            <input class="boton_detalle" id="cancela2" name="cancelar" type="submit" value="Cancelar" />
                            <input class="boton_detalle" id="comprar2" name="Comprar" type="submit" value="Comprar" />
                        </div>
                        <?php }else{
                            echo "Producto temporalmente agotado"; ?>
                            <input class="boton_detalle" name="Comprar" type="submit" value="Cancelar" />
                        <?php    
                        }
                        ?>
                    </form>
```

Al clickear el 1er boton #cancelar2, capturo el click con jquery / preventdefault y redirecciono a la pagina anterior, eso me queda ok.

El problema es el segundo boton, #comprar2 , al clickear necesito comprobar que el usuario está logueado al sistema ( variable $conectado booleana de PHP ), si está conectado ejecuta el submit, si no está conectado le mando una aviso y tambien redirecciono a otra pagina o al form de registro.

He intentado pero sin exito (jquery me complica porque la variable es php) , agradeceré cualquier ayuda antes de perder los pocos pelos que me quedan jaja.

Saludos !

Comment: Podrías usar ajax, una página de comprobación de si está logueado o no con php (con el uso de variables de sessiones) y dependiendo del valor devuelto, continuar con el submit o mostrar el mensaje. Por otro lado, no sería más cómodo mostrar ese mensaje y no mostrar el formulario si el usuario no está conectado?

Comment: Puedes comprobar la variable durante la generación del formulario, si tiene el valor adecuado para el envío generas un botón enviar que procese el formulario. Si no lo tiene, generas en su lugar un tercer botón que realiza la operación que describes.

Comment: Estoy en la pagina detalle.php y el tema es que los botones cancelar y comprar dependen de el mismo form, al hacer submit se dispara el action y redirecciona a la pagina carrito.php donde ya suma el item. Tendría que aprender como deshabilitar el boton por html a la carga ..

Answer (score 2):

las `variables` no están hechas para preservar información a lo largo de accesos subsiguientes.
Deberías usar [Sesiones](http://php.net/manual/es/book.session.php) para realizar dicha validación , Habilitando `session_start();` en todos las páginas que requieren saber el estado de estas.
En tu `login` tendrías algo así (Ejemplo básico)

```
<?php      
   session_start();
   if("UsuarioRegistrado") /*Verificar en la base de datos */ 
      $_SESSION['logueado'] = true;
?>
```

En el Carrito de Compra harías lo siguiente para validar si está Logueado

```
<?php      
   session_start();
   if (isset($_SESSION['logueado']) && $_SESSION['logueado'] == true)
       /* Realizar la Compra o Añadir al Carrito */
   else
      header('Location: '."UrlDelLogin");/*redireccionamiento*/
 ?>
```

Comment: Si, gracias por la respuesta, ya implementé sesiones, la variable $conectado la tomo de la comparación con la session, el problema es que en la home listo cajas con productos, al clickear en uno de ellos voy a detalle.php donde se ve una imagen mas grande, los detalles del producto y los botones cancelar y comprar . No se como pueda deshabilitar el boton comprar por html o php , ya que debe hacerse ni bien muestro detalle.php

Comment: Gracias a las respuestas pude razonarlo mejor ... pude resolver con jquery , al boton comprar le puse un id=cancelar3 , capturo el evento click  preventdefault , muestro un alerta y vuelvo a la pagina anterior.

Comment: Graciasssssss !!!!!

Comment: Si resolvió su inconveniente.  Marcar mi respuesta.